# Does Java Bean in the resultset with empty columns affects memory/size significantly?

Tags: java

This might sound a dumb question, but I could not find a lot of stuff about this (other than this article: https://plumbr.eu/blog/memory-leaks/reducing-memory-consumption-by-20x).

The question is: We're going to query Oracle database table which has 20 columns. We created a Java bean which maps to all the 20 columns. Now using Spring JDBC, we execute a query which only selects 3 columns (out of 20) and we set only the three properties in the bean (total properties=20), which means the rest of the 17 properties should be null. Now we use this resultset (having 3 fields populated, but 17 as null) for processing, for passing on between layers etc.

Is this going to affect the total memory used by the Java program significantly, especially when we are going to pull few hundred DB records or Java would somehow internally optimize it? Would it be better to just create a bean which has only 3 fields (which we need as part of our query?)

We're using JDK 1.8, Spring 4, oracle 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this going to affect the total memory used by the Java program

Short answer - yes, it will.

> Significantly?

well, it depends on what do you mean by "significantly".

When an instance of a class is created - it occupies some particular space.

The actual size of memory used (object footprint) depends on many things, in particular on:

- the types of the fields in the bean

  - if it is a primitive - each field has a particular number of bytes reserved [see spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3)
  - for reference type (Object and it's descendants) - reference also occupies 4 or 8 bytes
- Memory alignment
- JVM implementation
- JVM parameters
- ...

If you have 17 properties set to null we could assume that you've got those fields declared as non-primitive ones. So you might expect 68 or 136 bytes "wasted" if you do not use those fields. Or even more. The question is - is that too much for you?

You could instrument the actual objects you have and compare the memory footprints and decide if it is ok for you or not

> or Java would somehow internally optimize it

I'm not aware of that. But will be nice if anyone could shed some light on that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Micklesh, that makes sense to me. I'll wait for more inputs before accepting the answer.